# Kotlin JavaScript: Bundle for usage in React app

Tags: reactjs, kotlin-js

I have a Kotlin JS project that I like to export so that it can be used in a non-Kotlin React app.

Things I tried (let's say the module is called `exportedlib`):

1. Export it as CommonJS module, compiling it with `gradlew compileKotlinJs`.

I then copied `build/js/packages/exportedlib/kotlin/exportedlib.js` to the React app and imported it with `import exportedlib from './exportedlib'` in App.js.

When compiling with `npm start` I then get this error message: `Module not found: Can't resolve 'kotlin'`

2. I then also imported kotlin.js from `build/js/packages_imported/kotlin/1.3.72/kotlin.js` into the React app.

Then I get the error message:

```
./src/kotlin.js
  Line 2:39:      'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
```

3. As above didn't work I also added the browser target in build.gradle and exported it with `gradlew browserDistribution`.

Then I get these error messages from npm:

```
./src/exportedlib.js
  Line 1:1:      Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 1:112:    'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 1:123:    'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 1:500:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
// ... a lot of other "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" error messages
```

Can anybody help me to export a Kotlin JS lib so that it can be used in a React app?

Here's my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js' version '1.3.72'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-js"
}

kotlin.target.nodejs { }

// added as above didn't work
kotlin.target.browser { }

compileKotlinJs.kotlinOptions.moduleKind = "commonjs"
```

**Update**

[vanyochek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62513712/8837882)'s answer works for me when exported with `./gradlew compileProductionExecutableKotlinJs`, but only works for Kotlin 1.4 M2 with experimental IR backend.

Any solution for Kotlin 1.3 would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I have same issues. Did you managed it to work somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `1.4-M2` version of Kotlin and IR backend.
You need to change `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js' version '1.4-M2'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-js"
}

kotlin {
    js(IR) {
        useCommonJs()
        browser {}
        nodejs {}
        binaries.executable()

        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.moduleKind = "commonjs"
        }
    }
}
```

and settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }

        mavenCentral()

        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
}
rootProject.name = 'exportedlib'
```

After compilation of JS just add `exportedlib.js` to your React project.

Note: Kotlin `1.4-M2` and IR backend aren't stable.

Comment: It works for me when exported with the newly introduced Gradle task compileProductionExecutableKotlinJs.

I'd still prefer a solution for Kotlin 1.3 as it's quite a huge project and wouldn't like to use unstable Kotlin 1.4 M2 yet. But if within 2 weeks no-one finds a solution for 1.3 I will accept your answer.

But thanks for your answer, it helped me to get it running!